# How to check actual memory leaks during runtime using Valgrind?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, memory-leak-detector

In some programs some of the allocated memory is not destroyed at all, but they are required for the entire run time of the program. Hence, generally considered safe.

But there are other objects which are not intended for the entire run time of the program, but not destroyed due to developer misses. These are the actual memory leaks which should be addressed.

When we run the following Valgrind command, it only displays the total leaks after program execution ends. Hence, could someone clarify how to differentiate above two scenarios from Valgrind leak check output.

Command I used to detect memory leaks;

```
valgrind --log-file=valgrind_output.txt --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./MyTestProgram
```

Typical output at the end of execution;

```
==10108== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10108==    definitely lost: 392,323 bytes in 1,164 blocks
==10108==    indirectly lost: 178,120 bytes in 4,283 blocks
==10108==      possibly lost: 170,155,118 bytes in 3,347,087 blocks
==10108==    still reachable: 263,778,326 bytes in 3,935,669 blocks
```

Is there a feature in Valgrind like Tap in IBM Purify tool, which can detect currently leaked memory during runtime?

Comment: For debugging and leak-hunting purposes, it may be useful to deallocate global variables before terminating, even though it's technically useless. Indeed, you still want to know if these variables are indirectly leaking memory (e.g. if you have a global instance of a class that encapsulates a class which leaks memory)

Comment: looks like a copy of this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/7945885/476681

Comment: Late follow-up on the above comment... consider an object with non-trivial destructor, one that does more than just releasing memory. Closing sockets, commiting to database, something like that.. If you just leave such an object dangling (e.g. by assigning it via `new` and then never calling `delete` on it), *that destructor will never be called*, even though the OS will clean up the memory space after the process terminates. That's why those valgrind leaks *should* be taken seriously.

Answer (score 4):

You can use 2 different techniques to do leak search during execution.

1. From the shell command, launch
   vgdb leak_check
   There are other optional arguments to leak_check monitor commands, e.g. to
   find reachable memory, or just the memory that increased or ....
   See valgrind user manual for details:
   http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands
2. Inside your program:
   You can add in your program client requests to do leak search.
   E.g. insert "calls" to VALGRIND_DO_LEAK_CHECK  or VALGRIND_DO_ADDED_LEAK_CHECK
   See
   http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.clientreqs
   for more details

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a feature in Valgrind like Tap in IBM Purify tool, which can detect currently leaked memory during runtime?

No, there isn't. Valgrind can't know if there is a leak, unless the program finished, because it can't know what will be released when the program ends.

Comment: No may well be true, but your technical objection's a little hollow - it could at least make an educated guess using garbage collection style heuristics.

Comment: @TonyD Personally, I prefer solid facts about whether my program leaks memory, and not guesses. And there are no ways to say with 100% certainty that some memory is not released.

Comment: That's just pig-headed.  If you're beginning troubleshooting a memory problem you typically don't start with "solid facts" about the cause, you start with speculation and probabilistic indicators that guide your investigation.  Anyway... whatever... sorry for encouraging you to consider what's possible....

Comment: Garbage collection style analysis at runtime can reveal that there are no remaining pointers to anywhere within a block of memory, in which case that block of memory has indeed been leaked... right?  (This is true in C++ at least, in which it's illegal to increment a pointer to strictly outside a block of memory and then back again; it may not be true in C).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your program deliberately crash during run to make sure you can inspect allocated memory at that point. You can do this by adding a signal handler for some user defined signal like SIGUSR1.

```
signal(SIGUSR1, myhandler);
```

in your handler then you do something like this:

```
printf("debug exit!\n"); 
int *ptr = 0; 
*ptr = 0xdeadbeef;
```

You can then send this signal to your app like this:

```
kill -s SIGUSR1 `ps -aux| grep myapp | head -n -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Then you can inspect differences in numbers of allocated objects. If you know that numbers should remain same or if some number keeps growing then you can inspect the place where that happens and see if you have a memory leak there.